# Somewhat Obfuscated Serial With SIM800L and Uno R3

Tags: serial, gsm

I am successfully communicating with my SIM800L from my UNOR3 aside form some errors. But the biggest problem is with the serial monitor.

Responses from the SIM800L are somewhat obfuscated in that some characters are randomly wrong. See a snippet below:

```
Initializing...

OK

+C⸮T'⸮⸮b⸮j


OK

88l4110068165694746f

O⸮

+CQEG:Y⸮⸮H⸮⸮*⸮⸮C⸮
ERROR
⸮> H⸮⸮*⸮⸮
F⸮ROR
H⸮⸮
ERRO
H⸮⸮*⸮⸮
```

My code is also below.

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

//Create software serial object to communicate with SIM800L
SoftwareSerial mySerial(11,10); //SIM800L Tx & Rx is connected to Arduino #3 & #2

void setup()
{

  pinMode(2, INPUT);
  pinMode(3, OUTPUT);
  //Begin serial communication with Arduino and Arduino IDE (Serial Monitor)
  Serial.begin(115200);

  //Begin serial communication with Arduino and SIM800L
  mySerial.begin(115200);

  Serial.println("Initializing...");
  delay(1000);

  mySerial.println("AT"); //Once the handshake test is successful, it will back to OK
  updateSerial();
  mySerial.println("AT+CSQ"); //Signal quality test, value range is 0-31 , 31 is the best
  updateSerial();
  mySerial.println("AT+CCID"); //Read SIM information to confirm whether the SIM is plugged
  updateSerial();
  mySerial.println("AT+CREG?"); //Check whether it has registered in the network
  updateSerial();
  mySerial.println("AT+CMGF=1"); // Configuring TEXT mode
  updateSerial();
  mySerial.println("AT+CNMI=1,2,0,0,0"); // Decides how newly arrived SMS messages should be handled
  updateSerial();
  mySerial.println("AT+CMGS=\"+447518103652\"");//change ZZ with country code and xxxxxxxxxxx with phone number to sms
  updateSerial();
  mySerial.print("System on!"); //text content
  updateSerial();
  mySerial.write(26);

  delay(1000);
}


int milli = millis();
void loop()
{
  if (digitalRead(2) == HIGH) {
    digitalWrite(3, HIGH);
  mySerial.println("AT+CMGS=\"+447518103652\"");//change ZZ with country code and xxxxxxxxxxx with phone number to sms
  updateSerial();
  mySerial.print("Button Pressed!"); //text content
  updateSerial();
  mySerial.write(26);
  } else {
    digitalWrite(3, LOW);
  }

  if (milli <= millis() - 500) {
    updateSerial();
    milli = millis();
  }
}

void updateSerial()
{
  //delay(300);
  while (Serial.available()) 
  {
    mySerial.write(Serial.read());//Forward what Serial received to Software Serial Port
  }
  while(mySerial.available()) 
  {
    Serial.write(mySerial.read());//Forward what Software Serial received to Serial Port
  }
}
```

The SIM800L runs off a separate power supply with a decoupling cap of 100n and the grounds are commoned.

Comment: Which SIM800L board are you using? What is the wiring and wire length between the uno and the module? Do you have level shifting in place for a possibly necessary 3.3V <-> 5V conversion?

Comment: Its a coreboard, one jumper wire and internal breadboard connections. I don't know what you mean by that unless you mean stepping down the serial voltage which did not help.

Comment: Do you have a link to the SIM800L board you're using?

Comment: I don't but it looks like this https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjHgIL9zO_lAhXpAmMBHQhiCqEQjhx6BAgBEAI&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.banggood.com%2FSIM800L-GSM-GPRS-Module-Board-MicroSIM-Transfer-Card-Core-Board-Quad-band-p-1086519.html&psig=AOvVaw0LLO-qboau_2vsBH7ne9uo&ust=1574023590691357

Comment: So what voltage do you give as VCC and what level shifting circuitry are you using? This is just the bare module with a capacitor, you need to directly feed it with the necessary voltage of 3.4 to 4.2V and need at least level shifting from 5V to the target VCC.

Comment: It takes 3.8 v from my external power supply

Answer (score 1):

Here is a good documentation: https://lastminuteengineers.com/sim800l-gsm-module-arduino-tutorial/ --

Did you add a voltage divider to the RX pin? 
If Arduino drive 5 Volt to the module's pin, the module might be destroyed.

The module has an automatic baud rate detection, so 115200 baud should be OK. 
Do you configured your terminal with 115200 baud for the serial communication?

While sending, the Software Serial switches off all interrupts to make the micro clock more accurate. That might distort a timer interrupt for the hardware serial (but I don't really know, whether it needs one).

You changed the pins 2 and 3 for software serial (as from the example) to `SoftwareSerial mySerial(11,10);` Did you add the connections to the right pins. (RX?? <--> TX??)?

And last but not least. The axample uses 9600 baud for both serial interfaces. Perhaps your decision 115200 is too high.

Comment: I originally followed that, so tried changing the pins and baudrate which helped because with 9600 the chip wouldn’t respond and with the voltage divider from that tutorial I had the same issue.

Comment: @JamesConway Please check if you connected pin 11 of the arduino  to the TX pin of the module and pin 10 to the RX pin of the module. And check if you set your Serial Terminal in the Arduino ID to 115200 baud as you have configure the  hardware serial for 115200 baud too. By looking at the Serial output  I would say you have problems with the connection from the uno to the PC. So the baud thing is the most probable.